# Using virtual functions in C++ with vectors

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class called Matrix which has a function transpose. I also have a derived class Matrix2 which is inherited publicly from Matrix

```
class Matrix
{
 public:
    Matrix();
    ...
    Matrix Transpose(void);
...
    };

class Matrix2 : public Matrix
    {
     public:
        Matrix2();
        ...
      };
```

In my main code, I tried this.

```
vector <Matrix2> myMatrix2;
vector <Matrix> *b = &myMatrix2;
```

to do this

```
b->transpose();
```

But I get the following error

error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::vector<_Ty> *' to 'std::vector<_Ty> *'

What is wrong...

What is the way to access the transpose function from Matrix class in vector?

I get the following error.

```
error C2039: 'transpose' : is not a member of 'Matrix2'
```

Thanks

Comment: What's right? `vector<X>` and `vector<Y>` are completely different, unrelated types. Their pointers are not compatible.

Comment: Just because B is derived from A does not mean they are the same type.

Comment: What is the way to access the transpose function from Matrix class in vector<Matrix2>?

Comment: Anything publicly derived should be directly accessible from your Matrix2 objects.  You would not be accessing a function in Matrix from Matrix2, you would be accessing the derived function in Matrix2

Comment: I tried that, but the I was not able to access it. It says that the transpose function is not defined for Matrix2. Do I have to define the function prototype in Matrix2?

Answer (score 2):

You try to convert different types that have no (user-defined) conversion.

That's impossible.

`vector <Matrix2>` is not assignable to `vector <Matrix>&`, they have no common base. This is not Java, and there is no `vector<?>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you instantiate a template on a derived class, the template instantiation **is not** automatically derived from the same template instantiated with the base class.

Because those template instantiations are not related by inheritance, using one as if it was derived from / was the other is not possible. Forcing the compiler with a `reinterpret_cast` results in **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: Ironically, if you ***specialize*** it, it _could_ be derived :/ I find this explanation very confusing. Not enough "covariance", if you ask me.

Comment: @sehe: Damn, I really let a specialise slip in there. Good catch.

Comment: Huh. +1 for the wording fix. However, a compilation error is not Undefined Behaviour... (Lol @ **[ninja edit wars](http://i.imgur.com/MBG6NrT.png)**